# GRID.mvc issue in changing language [ASP.net MVC 4]

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using [Grid.Mvc](http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) in my project and I want to change the language of grid. To do that First I created and `Gridmvc.lang.fr.js` file For my language :

```
    /***
* Grid.Mvc French language (fr-FR) http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/
*/
window.GridMvc = window.GridMvc || {};
window.GridMvc.lang = window.GridMvc.lang || {};
GridMvc.lang.fr = {
    filterTypeLabel: "Type: ",
    filterValueLabel: "Valeur:",
    applyFilterButtonText: "Applique",
    filterSelectTypes: {
        Equals: "Egale",
        StartsWith: "commance par",
        Contains: "contient",
        EndsWith: "fini par",
        GreaterThan: "plus que",
        LessThan: "moin que"
    },
    code: 'fr',
    boolTrueLabel: "Vrai",
    boolFalseLabel: "faux",
    clearFilterLabel: "Vide"
};
```

Then in my view I made this :

```
    @Html.Grid(Model).Named("offresGrid").Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Add(item => item.REGION.NOM)
                                .Filterable(true)
                                .Sortable(true); ...
                            }).WithPaging(20)
    <script>
        $(function () {
            pageGrids.offresGrid.lang = GridMvc.lang.fr;
         });
</script>
```

This a part of `gridmvc.js` :

```
//load current lang options:
    this.lang = GridMvc.lang[this.options.lang];
    if (typeof (this.lang) == 'undefined')
        this.lang = GridMvc.lang.en;
```

But it dosn't work when i click on `Filter Icon` an empty Popup is opned with no value or button. 
Any one know how to change the language to Lang.fr by default ?

Comment: Have you referenced this library `Gridmvc.lang.fr.js` in your View?

Comment: Have you an error in your js debugger?

Comment: @lnanikian I forgot to refernce it. Also How can I make the Lang.fr the default Language ?  I have Updated my question and add new answer to mark it sloved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to change the current language by default, then you will just need to put the `Gridmvc.lang.fr.js` reference in your Layout and this script also:

```
  <script>
    $(function () {
        pageGrids.offresGrid.lang = GridMvc.lang.fr;
     });
 </script>
```

Regarding this snippet in `GridMVC.js`:

```
    this.lang = GridMvc.lang[this.options.lang];
    if (typeof (this.lang) == 'undefined')
    this.lang = GridMvc.lang.fr;//try this but I am not sure. Because it supposes to update the lang section
                                            // Where the lang is situated or add the first code above there.
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: it's in the same folder with gridmvc.js, changing gridmvc.Lang.en to gridmvc.lang.fr dosn't slove the problem to set it up by defaluts.

Comment: Could you make a rapid search in `gridmvc.js` to find Lang.en and I think you will need to edit it. And see how is it defined so you can create the same for `french` with `Grid.lang.fr` it could work

Comment: Thank's a lot You gave me a great idea, i just copied the content of `gridmvc.Lang.fr.js` file into my `gridmvc.js` file and the i changed this line like this `this.lang = GridMvc.lang.fr;` instead of this : `   this.lang = GridMvc.lang[this.options.lang];` and it worked thanks a lot

Comment: can i get your mail ?

Comment: Also i got an other issue can you take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268037/connection-string-trouble-metadataexception

Comment: use the @maxicecilia solution which is without modifying the gridmvc script and setting the language!

Answer (score 4):

I just find out another way to solve this, I hope it helps someone else.
I created my own lang file

```
gridmvc.lang.es.js
```

Included it after the mvcgrid.js in a bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mvcgrid").Include(
    "~/Scripts/gridmvc.js",
    "~/Scripts/gridmvc.lang.es.js"));
```

And then used SetLanguage to use it:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).SetLanguage("es").Columns(...)...
```