# Connection String Trouble MetaDataException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, connection-string

I got two models in my project. When I added the second models I got this error in all account page:

```
System.Data.MetadataException: The specified schema is not valid. Errors:
(8.6): error 0040: the nclob type is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification.

At line 34 of `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` : 

    using (var context = new UsersContext())
Ligne 33 :                     {
Ligne 34 :                         if (!context.Database.Exists())
Ligne 35 :                         {
Ligne 36 :                             // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
```

and those my connection string :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="User Id=devart;Password=1234;Data Source=localhost:1521" providerName="Devart.Data.Oracle" />
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ModelMAE.csdl|res://*/Models.ModelMAE.ssdl|res://*/Models.ModelMAE.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521;PASSWORD=1234;USER ID=TEST&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

`usercontext` Connection String1 :

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

`UserContext` connectionString 2 :

```
public class EntitiesMAE : DbContext
{

    public EntitiesMAE() : base("name=EntitiesMAE")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<OFFRE> OFFRE { get; set; }

    public DbSet<REGION> REGION { get; set; }
}
```

The problem's in seconde connection string `entities` when I remove it every thing works. 
Please How to fix it ?

Comment: I am using also two entities in a Project. I don't think it can be the problem. Could you update your question with the code of `UserContext` class.

Comment: Witch one you mean `myModel.context.cs` file ?

Comment: No, the `UsersContext` class. What you use in the `using` clause.

Comment: sorry but I can't figure it , I'm nweebie, can you give me the path of file where to find it ?

Comment: Just press F12 when your mouse is on `new UsersContext()` on line 32. And then paste the code of this class.

Comment: @lnanikian I have update my question check it please

Comment: Where do you use the second Entities? Because it seems. In the line 34, you just use the first connection string. Can you change this provider? `Devart.Data.Oracle` to the Microsoft one that you can find here a this [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/)

Comment: I use the seconde entities just to acces to my dataBase, it has no relation with the first one.

Comment: Then it should work. I use also 2 entities in the same project. Viewing your error it is more a problem with a type than your connectionstring. You can check on your databases the type used and then compare with C# type

Comment: When I remove the seconde connection string the Account page begin working fine again. But when I add it, the connection string, the Account page stop working.

Comment: Can I get your email ? i will send you my project to see it ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Oracle installed in my machine. If you put more code and where you use the second connectionstring I can see what I can do. Or you can create another simple project with the second connectionstring and see if you can access in the database.

Comment: I have Updated My post chek it please And My seconde string work fine (On other page of project). And the First Connection String works fine (I can Login, Logout Register ...)only when I remove the seconde ConnectionString.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51448/discussion-between-lnanikian-and-chlebta)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's related to this problem:

http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=21488

This article recommends two approaches. 
1.Disable Conventions (I wouldn't recommend this)
2.Use OracleEntityProviderConfig to configure Workarounds.IgnoreSchemaName = true

They also mention using a specific DbContext Template, which you can find from this article (I hate just posting links, but there's way too much information there to summarize):

http://blog.devart.com/entity-developer-ef-code-first-dbcontext-template.html

However, this was written for EF 4.1, and you don't say what version of EF you're using... so i'm not sure if any of this still applies to whatever version you may be using.

So the gist is that you can't just replace the provider with no other changes. You're going to have to make some other changes, and I would suggest generating code with the DevArt DbContext template using similar code and see what it produces, then put that code in your app.

Also, your code is obviously wrong.  You're using connection strings that don't exist (You say the the connection string is called Entities, but your code is using a connection string called EntitiesMAE), you also say your second context is called UserContext, but your code is called EntitiesMAE.  I suggest cleaning up your code so that it has your REAL code, because otherwise we're just trying to help you with code that isn't valid.